# Returning a List[String] using a comma vs not using a comma

Tags: powershell

how does putting a comma before a list affect its type?

Have a look at the following code:

```
function StartProgram
{
    $firstList = getListMethodOne
    Write-Host "firstList is of type $($firstList.gettype())"

    $secondList = getListMethodTwo
    Write-Host "secondList is of type $($secondList.gettype())"
}

function getListMethodOne
{
    $list = new-object system.collections.generic.list[string]
    $list.Add("foo") #If there is one element, $list is of type String
    $list.Add("bar") #If there is more than one element, $list is of type System.Object[]
    return $list 

}

function getListMethodTwo
{
    $list = new-object system.collections.generic.list[string]
    $list.Add("foo")
    $list.Add("bar")
    return ,$list #This is always of type List[string]
}

StartProgram
```

Why is it, if you don't use a comma before returning `$list` in `getListMethodOne` it returns as type `System.Object[]`, whereas if you do use a comma as in `getListMethodTwo`, it is of type `List[string]` as expected?

PS: I'm using PSVersion 4.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you return collection, than PowerShell is kind enough to unravel it for you.
Unary comma creates collection with single element, so "external" collection gets unraveled and collection you want to return is kept.

I [blogged](http://becomelotr.wordpress.com/2010/10/05/unary-comma/) about it a while ago.

Two more things:

- `return` is used in PowerShell to leave function early, it's not needed to return something from function (any not captured output is returned)
- in PowerShell 4.0 you can use `Write-Output -NoEnumerate $collection` to prevent unraveling your collection.

Comment: Why in getListMethodOne, is the type returned as System.Object[], when I declared it as List[String] ?

Comment: Once `List[String]` is unraveled, each element of it is send down the pipeline. We have more than one, so PowerShell will store results as System.Object[]. You declared type of variable within function scope. That doesn't have effect on function result if type is following into "let's make it better for pipeline". If that is the case, you need to "protect" your collection with unary comma or tell PowerShell to `Write-Output` with `-NoEnumerate`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full answer, but I would bet this relates to PowerShell's 'flattening' behaviour.

By using the unary operator ',' you are creating a new collection wrapper around the $list object. After PowerShell 'flattens' this, you see the object that was inside the wrapper.

A fuller explaination here: http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/09/24/effective-powershell-item-8-output-cardinality-scalars-collections-and-empty-sets-oh-my/